# SalesforceDX CLI "sObject type 'SourceMember' is not supported" with source pull

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm trying to pull down the current source for a sandbox org I've just connected to. General steps were:

1. Connect to the org.
   `sfdx force:auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com -a someOrg`
2. Create the project
   `sfdx force:project:create -n thatSandbox`
3. Switch into new project directory
4. Attempt to pull down the current org source
   `sfdx force:source:pull -u someOrg`

On the last step it fails with:

> ERROR running force:source:pull:
>   MemberName, IsNameObsolete FROM SourceMember WHERE RevisionNum >
>                                   ^
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:52
>   sObject type 'SourceMember' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a
>    custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

The sandbox is CS17, which is currently on Winter '18 Patch 4.4 (210.4.4).

Can I only do a source pull from a Scratch Org? If so, I guess I'd need to do a metadata retrieve from the sandbox and then convert to the Salesforce DX project format.

For what it's worth, [`SourceMember`](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_api_tooling_new_and_changed_objects.htm) (0MZ keyprefix) was added in beta in the Summer '17 release to the Tooling API:

> Represents a single sObject of all source that you are tracking in a scratch org

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are correct that you can only do a source pull from a Scratch Org. You can retrieve the source from a managed or unmanaged package. Just put everything you want to retrieve into an unmanaged package and then follow [these steps](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/07/migrating-existing-projects-salesforce-dx.html)